# Why does saving CSV file in S3 work in notebook cell, but not in terminal?

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I am trying to save a csv file on s3 by using a buffer object. The strange thing is that all works perfectly fine if I do it in jupyter notebook cell. I can read it again using pandas without any issues. Below is the code snippet:

```
csv_buffer = StringIO()
s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index = False)
_ = s3_resource.meta.client.put_object(Body = csv_buffer.getvalue(), Bucket = 'bucket', Key = 'temp.csv')
```

But, when I try to execute the same code dynamically in my program through command line interface, the file is being saved, albeit when I try to read it using pandas, I am getting error as follows: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte. As expected, when I download the file from s3, there are strange characters.

I have tried various solutions including new conda environment, using parquet instead of csv, adding ContentType parameter in put object. But nothing seems to work. Also, when I print the contents of csv buffer in my script, I can see the string contents as well. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What kind of strange characters?  How many?  Can you give us a hex dump of the start of the file?  Sometimes this happens when a file has a Unicode byte-order mark at the start, but those don't start with 0x80.

Comment: try  encoding='UTF-16' but without seeing your data that is a guess.

Comment: That didn't work. But instead of using boto3 resource meta client, I used boto3 client object directly. That seems to work for whatever reason.